# Error after predicting using CNN model loaded from disk

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I loaded my CNN model using

`model = load_model('./model/model.h5')`

This model loads well ( Though I do get warning messages: "Call initializer instance with the dtype argument instead of passing it to the constructor" )

However, when I try to predict using this model, I get the following error:

```
UnknownError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node conv2d/Conv2D}}]]
     [[dense_2/Softmax/_273]]
  (1) Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node conv2d/Conv2D}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored
```

Any idea how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I just didn't have CUDA installed on my system. Did that and now it's working!